# How to test an Android wear Watch face app?

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm trying to develop an Android wear Watch face using this [tutoriel](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-an-android-wear-watch-face--cms-23718)

The problem is when I try to test my app It gives me the error below :

```
Error running app: Default Activity not found
```

I searched a lot and nothing mention how to do this. Can Anyone guide me how to test a Watch face application ?

Comment: Can you give some more details about how you are testing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android Studio go to Run > Edit Configurations > Launch - set "Nothing" instead of "Default Activity" for mobile and wear modules

Comment: Is it possible to add an activity to do some stuff for example when tapping in the watch face ?

Comment: @J.M.J you should read more tutorials about the Android wear, just try to google. Stackoverflow is not the place for teaching your everything

Comment: Really ?!! Thank you for the advice, really thanks .. but I did, I searched a lot but no one has include a normal activity with the watch face. The only case I found it is for watch configuration and this one has its particular settings.